# Unable to use Toast message in loop in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-handler

I am making an android application in which

1) A loop begins and it checks whether connection is present

2)If it is, it performs TASK A and exits

3)if it isn't, it displays a TOAST message
  and then goes to step 1

To implement this, I tried putting my Toast message in a loop and trying

1)Creating a class which extended Asynch Tasks and displaying the Toast in doBackground()

2)Creating a handler . I displayed the Toast message in postDelayed

3)Displaying toast within runOnUiThread()

All of them met the same fate

For a small value (<10s), the App would halt indefinitely

For a large value (=30s), the App would force close

```
  int t=0;
  while (!t=1)
            {
                ConnectionCheck2 cd = new ConnectionCheck2(mContext);
                Boolean isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

                if (isInternetPresent)
                {
                  //TASK A
                    t=1;
                }
                else
                {
                    //made call to Handler, Asynch Tasks and runOnUiThread   here to display the Toast message below
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Internet is NOT connected",
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           }
```

}

The class ConnectionCheck constructor is initialized with the context of the class displaying the toast message. It has a method called isConnectingToInternet(), which checks whether internet connection is there. Authenticity of this class and function has been confirmed.

I tried

```
public void doSomeWork()
{

 final Timer someTimer= new Timer ();
    someTimer.schedule (new TimerTask () {


        @Override
        public void run()
        {

           ConnectionCheck2 cd = new ConnectionCheck2(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext());
            final Boolean isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
            runOnUiThread (new Thread(new Runnable() {
             public void run()
             {
               if (isInternetPresent)
                  {

                    Change();
                    someTimer.cancel();


                  }
                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(),"NOT Connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                         }
                       }));
                        }
                    }, 1000, 5000);

                    if (g==1)
                    {
                     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), "Internet is connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

          }//doSomeWork
                      public void Change()
                        {
                             g=1;

                          }

                //g is declared as a global variable
```

However, if i initially put the net off and turn it on, Internet is connected doesn't get displayed

I put the toast message in the runOnUithread() But my problem is that , if i remove the control condition then, the control first goes to, the toast  message which says "internet is connected" (the statement following the timer) and then to the "NOt connected" one. Also, when , Internet connectivity is found, and timer.cancel() is executed, the control doesn't go to the statement following the timer,instead it exits. As per my thinking, first the timer module should have been executed and then the statement succeeding it should have been executed, iff timer.cancel() condition was true

Comment: the toast will definitly not be visible in 1st and 3rd case . You need to pass the result into onPostExecute() method and display the toast there as it runs on uithread so no need of 2nd case

Comment: Display a Toast in doInBackground() should make your app crash actually, as `doInBackground` is not on the UIThread, but displaying a Toast should be on the UIThread.

Comment: And also what you need exactly? Network Connection or Internet Connection? If latter then you seriously need a different concept which is not a simple API implementation

Comment: @NicolasSimon I think a thread in a secondary thread is not pretty implementation. onPostExecute() is better option

Comment: Okay, so by  1st you mean the Async Task and by 3rd you mean runOnUiThread, right ?

Comment: @therealprashant I was saying that showing Toast in doInBackground was bad idea.
Anyway, here if you have no Internet connection, you'll create an infinite loop, displaying a Toast again and again (which makes your app crash)

Comment: Yes exactly and please post your exact requirement to serve you better

Comment: My problem is that the Toast message doesn't get printed as long as the loop runs. only once the network connection is there that  it prints the message .That is when the exit condition is satisfied.

Comment: @Nicolas Simon -It checks for internet connection continuously. So if the App is running on my cell. I initially switch off the net deliberately. After a few minutes of running the app, I turn the net connection. So it wont crash

Comment: @therealprashant -These are my requirements. Task A's implementation won't affect the outcome. I just need a way to print the TOAST message when the while loop is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While loops is not a good way to go, you can run TimerTask to run after every specified value of time.

```
Timer someTimer= new Timer ();
someTimer.schedule (new TimerTask () {
        @Override
        public void run () {
          // do your Checking here, for toast use runOnUIThread() or handler.

        }
    }, 0, 100);
```

**Notes:**

- 0 is for run on call
- 100 is to run every 100 of a second.

**Update**

```
    final Timer someTimer = new Timer ();
    someTimer.schedule (new TimerTask () {

        @Override
        public void run () {

            ConnectionCheck2 cd = new ConnectionCheck2 (MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext ());
            final Boolean isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet ();
            runOnUiThread (new Thread (new Runnable () {
                public void run () {

                    if (isInternetPresent) {

                        Change ();
                        someTimer.cancel ();

                        return;
                    }
                    Toast.makeText (MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext (), "NOT Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();

                }
            }));
        }
    }, 0, 5000);

    if (g == 1) {
        Toast.makeText (MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext (), "Internet is connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();

    }

}
```

Comment: I need to use a while loop , so that it checks till net connection is found and perform the task A. In the meanwhile, I want the user to know that net connection wasn't performed dur to the TOAST

Comment: I incorporated your code in the else part and its giving me a FORCE CLOSE Message.

Comment: I've read about timers and I've even tried it in this program itself in vain. However, I have one doubt , when does the control leave the timer ?

Comment: No No, do not use while loop.

Comment: oh wait.. timer.cancel()

Comment: this is based on you logic, when you found internet connected or inside your TRUE condition, cancel the timer.

Comment: Ya, I realized that a bit late. I can't implement it now, but asap I will . The problem with while loop is that it executes very fast and hence my output is not as desired.Am i right in saying this ? Thanks for your help. I hadn't ever thought about it in that direction.

Comment: Whats the problem now?

Comment: Use runonuithread only when you need to show toast not for checking internet conectivity

Comment: Timer I suggested is the replacement for your while loop

Comment: No need to use `Change();`

Comment: I used it to make sure the control goes to Internet is connected after the timer module executes only.

Comment: still you are not getting the toast

Comment: i am getting the toast. My problem is that the control should first go to the timer function and then to the line succeeding it. But the control goes to the line succeding the timer function and then to the timer

Comment: because you said so, On line `1000, 5000` here 1000 is the first execution time, it means it will run after 1 second and then every 5 secs

Comment: gosh! Thanks :) That's some logic. I'll try it asap